# ComboBox Dependiente c# entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

tengo un problema al enlazar combobox con entity framework, la cual hace poco tiempo estoy utilizando.

necesito enlazar 3 combobox seccion-cargo-sueldo

actualmente cargo el combobox de esta manera

```
public void llenaseccion()
    {
        try
        {
            using (FrusanRecursosHumanosEntities db = new FrusanRecursosHumanosEntities())
            {
                var seccion = db.TB_Seccion.ToList();
                if (seccion.Count > 0)
                {
                    combo_seccion.DataSource = seccion;
                    combo_seccion.DisplayMember = "Descripcionseccion";
                    combo_seccion.ValueMember = "Idseccion";
                    if (combo_seccion.Items.Count > 1)
                    {
                        combo_seccion.SelectedIndex = -1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
public void llenacargo()
    {
        try
        {
            using (FrusanRecursosHumanosEntities db = new FrusanRecursosHumanosEntities())
            {
                var cargo = db.TB_Cargo.ToList();
                if (cargo.Count > 0)
                {
                    combo_cargo.DataSource = cargo;
                    combo_cargo.DisplayMember = "Descripcioncargo";
                    combo_cargo.ValueMember = "Idcargo";
                    if (combo_cargo.Items.Count > 1)
                    {
                        combo_cargo.SelectedIndex = -1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
public void llenasueldo()
    {
        try
        {
            using (FrusanRecursosHumanosEntities db = new FrusanRecursosHumanosEntities())
            {
                var sueldo = db.TB_Sueldo.ToList();
                if (sueldo.Count > 0)
                {
                    combo_sueldo.DataSource = sueldo;
                    combo_sueldo.DisplayMember = "Descripcionsueldo";
                    combo_sueldo.ValueMember = "Idsueldo";
                    if (combo_sueldo.Items.Count > 1)
                    {
                        combo_sueldo.SelectedIndex = -1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
```

necesito que se carguen en cascada los 3 combobox se que en el evento selectedindexchanged se debebe pasar la variable id.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que ir anidando las llamadas pasando el valor del combo anterior

```
public void llenaseccion()
{
    using (FrusanRecursosHumanosEntities db = new FrusanRecursosHumanosEntities())
    {
        var seccion = db.TB_Seccion.ToList();

        combo_seccion.DisplayMember = "Descripcionseccion";
        combo_seccion.ValueMember = "Idseccion";
        combo_seccion.DataSource = seccion;

        combo_seccion.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }

    int seccion = Convert.ToInt32(combo_seccion.SelectedValue);
    llenacargo(seccion);
}

public void llenacargo(int seccionId)
{
    using (FrusanRecursosHumanosEntities db = new FrusanRecursosHumanosEntities())
    {
        var cargo = db.TB_Cargo.Where(x=> x.IdSeccion == seccionId).ToList();

        combo_cargo.DataSource = cargo;
        combo_cargo.DisplayMember = "Descripcioncargo";
        combo_cargo.ValueMember = "Idcargo";

        combo_cargo.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }

    int cargo = Convert.ToInt32(combo_cargo.SelectedValue);
    llenasueldo(cargo);
}

public void llenasueldo(int cargoId)
{
    using (FrusanRecursosHumanosEntities db = new FrusanRecursosHumanosEntities())
    {
        var sueldo = db.TB_Sueldo..Where(x=> x.IdCargo = cargoId)ToList();

        combo_sueldo.DataSource = sueldo;
        combo_sueldo.DisplayMember = "Descripcionsueldo";
        combo_sueldo.ValueMember = "Idsueldo";

        combo_sueldo.SelectedIndex = -1;    
    }
}
```

Esta claro que cuando se produzca el evento

```
public void combo_seccion_SelectionChangeCommitted(...)
{
    int seccion = Convert.ToInt32(combo_seccion.SelectedValue);
    llenacargo(seccion);
}

public void combo_cargo_SelectionChangeCommitted(...)
{
    int cargo = Convert.ToInt32(combo_cargo.SelectedValue);
    llenasueldo(cargo);
}
```

Usa el evento `SelectionChangeCommitted` y no el `SelectedindexChanged` ya que si cargas en cascada se lanzara el event por cada item que genere el datasource

Comment: en la linea (x=> x.IdSeccion == seccionId) me marca un error de directiva de uso o referencia de ensamblado.

Comment: me respondo yo mismo me faltaba actualizar el diagrama de conexión.

Comment: La respuesta a esta pregunta me ayudo mucho en un trabajo que estoy pero mi duda es porque definís dos veces la misma variable